# Player characters used a Devastation Orb of Water underground

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, published-adventures, princes-of-the-apocalypse

The player characters got their hands on a Devastation Orb of Water. They decided that they wanted to use it against

> the Fire Cult's Temple

which is underground.

If they do use it underground, would the rain appear underground in the area where the item went off, or would the rain appear above ground on the surface?

Answer (score 8):

*Princes of the Apocalypse* says of [Devastation Orbs](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/devastation-orb) (p. 222-223):

> Regardless of the type of orb, its effect is contained within a sphere with a 1 mile radius.

And of the Orb of Water:

> When this orb detonates, it creates a torrential rainstorm that lasts for 24 hours. Within the area of effect, the rules for heavy precipitation apply, as detailed in chapter 5 of the Dungeon Master’s Guide. If there is a substantial body of water in the area, it floods after 2d10 hours of heavy rain, rising 10 feet above its banks and inundating the surrounding area.

The DMG section on ["Heavy Precipitation"](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/dmg/adventure-environments#HeavyPrecipitation) (p. 110) says:

> Everything within an area of heavy rain or heavy snowfall is lightly obscured, and creatures in the area have disadvantage on Wisdom (Perception) checks that rely on sight. Heavy rain also extinguishes open flames and imposes disadvantage on Wisdom (Perception) checks that rely on hearing.

If you put all that together, it will rain as described both underground and above ground, within a mile-radius sphere centered on the Orb.

Of course, D&D 5e emphasizes "Rulings not Rules", and the GM is free to rule exactly how that all plays out - but at a minimum, it's now heavily raining in the fire temple and any open flames are extinguished, and so on as described above.  No doubt that will vex some of the occupants of said temple to no end.

The DMG does not specify magical fire, so the default assumption is that the Orb will only extinguish mundane fire.

According to the Basic Rules, [fire elementals](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/fire-elemental) have the "Water Susceptibility" trait:

> For every 5 feet the elemental moves in water, or for every gallon of water splashed on it, it takes 1 cold damage.

Should there be any fire elementals in the Orb's range, they'll really get steamed, and I mean really steamed.

In fact, a magical torrential rain falling on a magical fire-thing is likely to create lots and lots of steam, possibly resulting in some damage.

On the bright side, the PCs can probably get their clothes steamed (you know, to get out the wrinkles) for free.